# How to add scroll bar for menu items?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf

I want to add long list as menu items but for that need to show scroll bar.
Here is my code-
so what should do for showing scrolling bar.

```
<p:splitButton value="#{divisionBean.division}" >

    <c:forEach items="#{sessionScope['proxyMgrMap']}" var="t">
    <p:menuitem value="#{t.key}" style="width: 140px !important;"
        itemLabel="#{t.value}" itemValue="#{t.value}"  ajax="false" action="#{loginBean.changeProxyManager}" >

                <f:param name="proxyOrgId" value="#{t.value.orgID}" />
                <f:param name="proxyOrgLevel" value="#{t.value.orgLevel}" />
                <f:param name="proxyEntityId" value="#{t.value.parentID}" />
                <f:param name="proxyDscId" value="#{t.value.mgrDscId}" />
                <f:param name="selSplitKey" value="#{t.key}" />

        </p:menuitem> 
    </c:forEach>

</p:splitButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

try css element `overflow:auto` for show scrolling automatically when size is increased from div